# StopIteration during search query using scholarly module in Python

Tags: python, iteration, iterable, google-scholar

I try to get details of particular papers from Google Scholar using a scholarly module in Python2.7. I want to collect details of 1000 papers and wrote below mentioned code.

```
seq = range(0,1,len(ResearchPaperNames))
for i in seq:
    pub = (next(scholarly.search_pubs_query(ResearchPaperNames[i]))
    print i
    # And further processing to extract data from pub, like author, citation, url
```

It gives me error after 10 to 12 iteration is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sony\Downloads\Google Scholar Data Extraction.py", line 25, in <module>
    pub = (next(scholarly.search_pubs_query(ResearchPaperNames[i])
StopIteration
```

I have gone through several answers available on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't fix it.

Please help me to fix StopIteration error

Comment: Your brackets in that line are not balanced, how does this code work at all?

Answer (score 3):

`next` takes an optional default value as a second parameter...

```
seq = range(0,1,len(ResearchPaperNames))
for i in seq:
    pub = next(scholarly.search_pubs_query(ResearchPaperNames[i]),None)
    print i
```

will stop the issue I think ... sort of ... basically there were no results for the given research paper, often times simply printing inside the loop can be enlightening also as a general rule of thumb, iterating over 0..len(array) to access its elements is something of an anti pattern

```
for paperName in ResearchPaperNames:
    pub = next(scholarly.search_pubs_query(paperName),None)
    if pub is None: 
       print "Error %s not found!"%paperName
    else:
       #process the publication
```

Comment: Thanks, Joran. I tried your code. I think it is the problem of python query search on Google scholar. In everyday, It is works for 80-90 iteration, after break out.